# Programmatically adding selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a problem with adding selectonemenu component of Primefaces at runtime. 
I added the selectonemenu but it doesnt display the name or attrbt of the objects , it shows references of them. 
Thank you for your time .

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/admin/admin.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="center">
        <h:form id="openposition">
            <h:panelGrid id="openpanelposition" columns="1">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{menu['menu.admin.openposition.name']}"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="positiontype" value="#{openPositionController.position}" converter="#{positionConverter}" panelStyle="width:180px"
                                 effect="fade" var="u" style="width:160px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{openPositionController.positionList}" var="position" itemLabel="#{position.name}" itemValue="#{position}" />
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{u.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:panelGrid id="unitgroup" columns="1">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="higherunit" value="#{openPositionController.unit}" converter="#{unitConverter}" panelStyle="width:180px"
                                     effect="fade" var="unit" style="width:160px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                     valueChangeListener="#{openPositionController.selectunit}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{openPositionController.unitList}" var="unit" itemLabel="#{unit.unitName}" itemValue="#{unit}" />
                        <p:ajax update="@this"/>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{unit.unitName}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

```
package tr.com.innova.hrm.web.controller.menucontroller;

/**
 * Created by mcan on 22/01/2015.
 */

import org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenu;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import tr.com.innova.hrm.model.entity.Position;
import tr.com.innova.hrm.model.entity.Unit;
import tr.com.innova.hrm.service.api.business.PositionService;
import tr.com.innova.hrm.service.api.business.UnitService;
import tr.com.innova.hrm.web.converter.UnitConverter;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItems;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@ManagedBean(name = "openPositionController")
@ViewScoped
public class OpenPositionViewController implements Serializable{

    private Position position;
    private Unit unit;
    private List<Position> positionList;
    private List<Unit> unitList;

    @ManagedProperty("#{positionService}")
    private PositionService service;

    @ManagedProperty("#{unitService}")
    private UnitService unitService;

    public UnitService getUnitService() {
        return unitService;
    }

    public void setUnitService(UnitService unitService) {
        this.unitService = unitService;
    }

    public Unit getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(Unit unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public List<Unit> getUnitList() {
        return unitList;
    }

    public void setUnitList(List<Unit> unitList) {
        this.unitList = unitList;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public List<Position> getPositionList() {
        return positionList;
    }

    public void setPositionList(List<Position> positionList) {
        this.positionList = positionList;
    }

    public PositionService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(PositionService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        positionList = service.loadAll();
        unitList = unitService.getAllUnit();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    }

    public void selectunit()
    {
        HtmlPanelGrid component = (HtmlPanelGrid) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":openposition:unitgroup");
        SelectOneMenu oneMenu = new SelectOneMenu();
        oneMenu.setRendered(true);
        oneMenu.setConverter(new UnitConverter());
        UISelectItems items = new UISelectItems();

        ValueExpression expr = getValueExpression("#{openPositionController.unitList}");
        items.setValueExpression("value", expr);
        oneMenu.getChildren().add(items);
        component.getChildren().add(oneMenu);

        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.update("openposition");
        context.update("openposition:unitgroup");
    }

    private ValueExpression getValueExpression(String expression) {
        ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext expressionContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        return expressionFactory.createValueExpression(expressionContext, expression, Object.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're indeed not doing exactly the same as you did in XHTML. You did not set the var, label, etc. Pretty clear. But why exactly would you like to do it in Java instead of in XHTML? XHTML is so much better suitable to creating/declaring/defining components in the view than that unreadable Java mess. It's really beyond me why starters need to create components in Java side instead of in XHTML side. There's **nothing** which can be done only in Java and not in XHTML. If you elaborate the concrete problem for which you incorrectly thought that you couldn't do it in XHTML, then we could answer it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i need unknown number of comboboxes in my project. We have units and unknown number of subunits of them. After selecting the mainunit, i need to add a selectonemenu to fill its subunit and after selecting that , i need to add another selectonemenu to fill its subunit recursively... @BalusC

Comment: Just use `<h:dataTable>`, `<ui:repeat>` or `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a collection of an arbitrary size?

Comment: How can i know if a unit has subunit or not without selecting a unit? Suppose i have unit1 unit2 and unit1 doesnt have subunit and unit2 has 1 subunit and that subunit has another 2 subunits. 1 combo,after selection add another combo if that one has subunit add onther combo and add another if a selected subunits has subunits ,etc... @BalusC

Comment: Just apply same logic in XHTML via `rendered` attribute or `<c:if>` tag as you would do in Java via `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for the future generations...
This is the way i've created a SelectOneMenu of PrimeFaces programmatically:

```
// Get context and expression factory
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionFactory ef = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

// Create panel grid
HtmlPanelGrid grid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
grid.setColumns(2);

// Create the select label
OutputLabel comboLabel = new OutputLabel();
comboLabel.setValue(obj.getNameFilter());
comboLabel.setFor(cmpName);
grid.getChildren().add(comboLabel);

// The biding expression of the select
ValueExpression comboExpr = ef.createValueExpression(context.getELContext(),
        "#{MbDinamicReports.valueCombo}", String.class);

// Create the select
SelectOneMenu comboBox = new SelectOneMenu();
comboBox.setId(cmpName);
comboBox.setValueExpression("value", comboExpr);
// Here the items are added
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
    item.setItemLabel("Label" + i);
    item.setItemValue("value" + i);
    comboBox.getChildren().add(item);
}
grid.getChildren().add(comboBox);
```

Comment: Explaining your code, and how it differs from the code posted in the question would greatly increase the quality of this answer.